# Proving the composition of two functions having partial derivatives has a partial derivative.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $N$ be open subset of $\Bbb R^n$,   $x \in N$

The function $f : N \to \Bbb R$ has a partial derivative at point $x$

Let $I$ be open interval in $\Bbb R$ with $f(N) \subset I $

The function $g: I \to \Bbb R$ have a derivative at $f(x)$

How do I prove that the compositon $g\circ f : N \to \Bbb R $ has a partial derivative at $x$

$\frac {\partial}{\partial x_i}(g\circ f)(x) = g'(f(x))\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)$
with component $i$?

Please show me a clear way to solve this.

Comment: do you have the multivariate chain rule to use? If so this is pretty much immediate. Otherwise, you'll need to work through the definition of the partial derivative. Do you know it?

Comment: Yes I know. But I dont know how to apply to this. Please show me clearly this proof. Thank you @JamesS.Cook

Comment: Can you prove the chain rule for the case $n = 1$, that is, ordinary functions of one real variable?

Comment: Yes @DanielFischer but here. I need to use multivariable.

Comment: But you're only considering one partial derivative. For that consideration, all other variables are constants. Thus the proof is exactly the same, just with a bit additional notation, instead of $x+h$, you write $x + h\cdot e_i$.

Comment: @B11b what Daniel Fischer recommends is logically equivalent to my answer. The derivative I write is merely a short-hand for the limiting process he points you toward.

Comment: Hmm.. Well! got it your solution perfectly:) @JamesS.Cook

Comment: @B11b glad to help, it would be wise to work through the problem as Daniel Fischer suggested, especially if you don't already know how to prove the single-variate chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $h = g \circ f$. Let us calculate the partial derivative at $p \in N $ with respect to the $j$-th coordinate. Observe that $\gamma(t) = p+te_j$ gives a line in the $j$-th coordinate direction for which $\gamma(0)=p$. The partial derivative of $h$ with respect to $x_j$ at $p$ is defined by 
$$ \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_j}(p)=\frac{d}{dt} \bigl( h \circ \gamma \bigr)(t) |_{t=0}
=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{ h(p+te_j)-h(p)}{t} $$
Consider,
$$
 \frac{d}{dt} \bigl( h \circ \gamma \bigr)(t)  = \frac{d}{dt} g( f (\gamma(t))) 
= g'(f(\gamma(t)) \frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t) )
$$
where I used the single-variate chain rule in the last equality. Now, if you understand the definition I used for the partial derivative, your result is obvious from what I've written. Although, I replaced $x$ with $p$.

Comment: Sorry but, in fact i dont understand how to write the first equation before "consider" :(

Comment: Please can you explain there a little bit.

Comment: Thourgh the definiton of limit. Okay! Got it:) thank you for help a lot :)

Comment: @B11b what I just added, the difference quotient, is usually how we define the partial derivative at $p$ in the $j$-th direction. However, the identity I write for the derivative makes it easier to steal this result from the real reason it's true; the single-variable chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments

Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ be an open set, $f:A\to\Bbb R^m$ a differentiable function, $c\in A$ and $v\in\Bbb R^n$ some unit vector. Let $x=c+hv$. Then $$\begin{aligned}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|f(c+hv)-f(c)-hDf(c)v\|}{\|hv\|}=0\iff\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+hv)-f(c)-hDf(c)v}h&=0\\\implies\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(c)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+hv)-f(c)}h&=Df(c)v\end{aligned}$$ so, in your case:
$$\color{green}{\frac{\partial (g\circ f)}{\partial x_j}(c)}=\color{green}{D(g\circ f)(c)e_j}=Dg(f(c))\circ \color{blue}{Df(c)e_j}=g'(f(c))\color{blue}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(c)}$$